# Burn the [bounce] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [bounce](/questions/tagged/bounce) tag covers a number of topics:

- [Bouncing Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235534/what-is-the-behavior-difference-between-return-path-reply-to-and-from)
- [Bouncing Animation in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768269/ipad-safari-disable-scrolling-and-bounce-effect)
- [Collision Detection/Physics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715592/bouncing-ball-logics)
- [JQuery Bounce Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167063/jquery-bounce-not-firing)
- [Google SEO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748881/is-bounce-rate-a-google-search-engine-factor)

Should we burn this tag?

Comment: It sounds like one of those tags that *could* be useful (like in the first and last question), but gets misused. The tag description, sadly, fits in the latter.